# Windows Server 2016 Any way to see current raid 5 setup status?

Tags: windows, raid

Im very impatient. I want to see some sort of percentage for a new raid 5 setup i started a hour or so ago. Is this possible? im not finding anything on it. I would like to watch it, like paint drying.

For anyone wondering im using 4 1tb drives, so i didnt expect it to be taking so long. When i used three of these drives on my windows 10 computer they only took a few moments to setup raid. (i think)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Get-StorageJob cmdlet in PowerShell which will return information about long-running Storage module jobs, such as a repair task (if the Storage Spaces is in use). If the other RAID technologies are in use then just use proprietary management consoles to manage the RAID array and check the current status.